# MVC Ninject I Don't want to have reference to data layer but only to service layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, repository-pattern, dto

I'm new in MVC and Ninject.....
Using Ninject I have something like this in my Global.asax Application_start()

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
```

in NinjectControllerFactory class I have something like this

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<IDbFactory>().To<DbFactory>().InRequestScope(); <-- DBFactory!
ninjectKernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();                <-- UnitOfwork!
ninjectKernel.Bind<IOrderService>().To<OrderService>();            <-- Service!
ninjectKernel.Bind<IRepository<Order>>().To<Repository<Order>>();  <-- Entities!
```

OK I DON'T LIKE IT AT ALL!

I don't want to have reference to my Data Layer and EF layer in UI...I would like to have reference only to Service layer and then pass data to and from my UI using DTO...

I create instances of my services injecting repository...for example...

```
public OrderService(IRepository<Order> OrderRepository)
```

I'm feeling confused and frustrated. Is there a way to initialize ninject not in my UI?

Thanks in advance!!!

JDBO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Gary. S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701062/gary-s) answered dynamic module loading `kernel.Load("*.dll");` is a solution but an important realization for me was that you have to somehow copy the un-referenced assemblies to the UI project bin folder so they can be found by Ninject and deployed properly.

Maybe there is a better way but I used a post build event in Visual Studio to copy the dll file(s).

Answer (score 7):

You can use ninject modules to break out your binds into neat little packages that live within their project domain. For example, you can define your dbfactory and UOW bindings in the DAL if you so desire and then just load all ninject modules using the dynamic module loading guidance provided by the wiki.

https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel

Comment: Great! Now in my UI I have only referenced service interfaces and dto...ehhehe...that's what I was looking for! Thanks!!!!!